# Why should exploratory analysis not be followed up with a confirmatory analysis in the same dataset?

Tags: dataset, exploratory-data-analysis

On the Wikipedia page for [data analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_analysis#Exploratory_and_confirmatory_approaches), the following claim is made. *"...one should not follow up an exploratory analysis with a confirmatory analysis in the same dataset. An exploratory analysis is used to find ideas for a theory, but not to test that theory as well."*  This claim is referenced to an obscure article, hidden behind a paywall with very little web presence to verify its existence.  If this was an important condition with data analysis, one would expect a more fundamental reference, even multiple references, to support this claim.

So, I'm wary of taking this statement as a given, especially with such a weak reference. My question is simple: Is this condition true and, if so, under what rationale (i.e. why) does a dataset disqualify itself from being analysed using both exploratory and confirmatory perspectives? A more solid reference would be a good start.

Comment: Recently asked [Is "Exploratory Data Analysis" Fundamentally At Odds With "P-Hacking"?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/602020/is-exploratory-data-analysis-fundamentally-at-odds-with-p-hacking).

Comment: @user2974951- different question. Also mine is more specific.

Comment: Very much related, also lots of links in that question. Have you read any of it?

Comment: Other possible duplicates: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/476222/why-cant-we-mix-exploratory-model-building-and-statistical-tests-for-validating https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/354535/examining-the-data-before-analysis-i-still-dont-know-what-im-looking-for

Comment: @user2974951. Yes. None of them answer my specific question hence I have asked it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["Examining the data" before analysis: I still don't know what I'm looking for](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/354535/examining-the-data-before-analysis-i-still-dont-know-what-im-looking-for) Please read the answer and take a careful look at the linked resources.

Comment: @dipetkov - that's a good answer. I missed that post. It didn't come up as a possible duplicate when I asked my question. Thanks for pointing it out. Much appreciated. (That answer should be referenced on Wikipedia). I will read the related references as well to get understand the "why".